# HDMI not displaying external monitor in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

My external monitor plugged to my laptop using VGA works fine, but when plugged with HDMI it does not work. The monitor and HDMI cable work fine when plugged into a Windows laptop.

The screen is detected in `Displays`. 
[image: Displays Screenshot]
The screen is not detected in `nvidia-settings`
[image: nvidia-settings]
The additional drivers are set as follows 
[image]
Here is the `lspci` output

```
~$ lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Device [104d:905a]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at d1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 7078 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller [8086:3b64] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Device [104d:905a]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 330M] [10de:0a2b] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Device [104d:905a]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 6000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at d1080000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GT216 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:0be2] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Device [104d:905a]
```

Comment: Any tips would be helpful. I am stuck for ideas.